# Do commands run from current directory in a shell script?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, scripting

In a bash shell script I tried these two versions:

```
java -jar abc.jar&
```

and

```
CMD="java -jar abc.jar&"
$CMD
```

The first verison works, and the second version complains that abc.jar cannot be found. Why?

Comment: The two versions are equivalent (although the second is worse). Does `thisFile` contain spaces?

Comment: No spaces. Why would it work for the first one and not the second?

Comment: Because you already renamed it to `thatFile` when you ran the first version?

Comment: Well mv is only an example, I'm actually trying to run the java command.

Comment: How are you running the script?  Try with -x to see debug output.  Also, put in `echo $PWD` to see if it's where you think it is.

Comment: It works for me, I don't know what could be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands do run from current directory in a shell script.

This is why the first command in your test script worked.

The second command may not work because either `java` isn't in your `${PATH}` or `abc.jar` isn't in your `${CLASSPATH}`. You could `echo` these environment variables or `set +x` to debug your `bash` script.

Comment: `java -jar` does not use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. It only uses the `Class-Path` entry from the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Bash (and others) won't let you do backgrounding (`&`) within the value of a variable (nor will they let you do redirection that way or pipelines). You should avoid putting commands into variables. See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for some additional information.

What is the actual error message you're getting? I bet it's something like "abc.jar& not found" (note the ampersand) because the ampersand is seen as a character in the filename.

Also, the current directory for the script is the directory that it is run *from* - **not** the directory in which it resides. You should be explicit about the directory that you want to have your file in.

```
java -jar /path/to/abc.jar&
```